# CKFinder: How to create small, medium, and large images automatically from image upload

Tags: coldfusion, ckeditor, ckfinder

I am looking for a way to make small, medium, and large copies of an image automatically when uploaded through CKFinder 2.5.  Basically I want the same image copied and resized to different sizes so that I can use different images for my responsive site.  The imageresize plugin does similar, but not quite what I am looking for since it is still initiated by the user.

I would prefer to add the code to the config file over adjusting code in the core folder.  I am using coldfusion, but I would appreciate ideas in any language possible so I can make something work.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You probably want to use code to do this.

Comment: Any chance you are using PHP?